# PasteSpecial Excel Table into Slide Placeholder PowerPoint VBA

Tags: excel, vba, layout, powerpoint, copy-paste

I'm sorry to be posting another PasteSpecial-question, but I haven't found something that relates precisely to what I'm trying to do.

I have some VBA code:

```
For Each Workbook In Workbooks

For Each Sheet In Workbook.Sheets

running_pp_app.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add running_pp_app.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly
Sheet.Range("a1:b2").Copy
running_pp_app.ActivePresentation.Slides(running_pp_app.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault, link:=msoCTrue

Next Sheet
Next Workbook
```

When I paste the Excel-range into a slide, I ultimately want to have the pasted range/shape occupying a placeholder in the slide-layout. I don't want it to be just some additional shape on the slide.

Ultimately, my goal is to be able to easily control all of the pasted ranges/shapes via master-layouts (via the UI, after my VBA runs). I don't know how to paste the linked OLE object into the slide so that it occupies a placeholder-position--so that it is the "content" in the "Title and Content" master-layout, for example.

How can I do this?

All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/pastespecial-excel-table-into-slide-placeholder/e5c9f24a-1285-402a-b414-4bac5c3f204e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was that this doesn't appear to be possible. This works to paste into a placeholder:

```
Sub PasteIntoPlaceholder()
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).Select
    ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault
End Sub
```

But as soon as you add the link parameter, it pastes as a separate shape, not in the placeholder.

This mostly corresponds to analogous actions in the user interface. A straight Paste onto a slide with a selected placeholder will insert the chart as expected, but a Paste Special will not.

**Revision:**

Following your suggestion, this mostly does the job. The placeholder shrinks to fit the pasted Excel object instead of the Excel object expanding to fit the placeholder, but hey, it works:

```
Sub PasteIntoPlaceholder()
    With ActiveWindow
        .View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault, Link:=msoCTrue
        .Selection.Cut
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).Select
        .View.Paste
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, John. However, there actually is a manual way to get a linked OLE object into a placeholder.

First, via the UI, paste-special the OLE object onto the slide. Then, cut the object. Then, click into the object-placeholder on the slide. Then, paste normal. The OLE-object will be retained (with the link), but it will also occupy the placeholder.

I tried to replicate this with VBA, but it wasn’t working the same way.

Can you confirm that you can replicate this manually and what VBA steps you would use to replicate it.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, John. Can you explain why this works using the view.paste method and does not seem to work with the shapes.paste method.

I tried doing something like:
`shapes.pastespecial...
shapes(3).select
shapes(3).cut
shapes(2).select
shapes(2).paste`

This method doesn't seem to work as yours does. Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why. It's just one of those VBA oddities. I learned it from John Wilson, who's a long-time PowerPoint programmer.

Comment: Ok, thanks again for your help, John. I'll be sure to thank John Wilson on the other post.