# How to paste an Excel chart into PowerPoint placeholder using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com, python-pptx

I have an excel file with a series of formatted charts on a tab called `Charts`.  I have named the charts, `Figure1`, `Figure2`, `Figure3`, etc.

I have an existing PowerPoint template. The template has 2 placeholders per slide (so that it can accommodate 2 charts per slide).

I would like to paste `Figure1` in the left placeholder of slide 3, and `Figure2` in the right placeholder of slide 3.  I want to do this in python as the data analysis is done in python and excel is used to share stored results with colleagues.

**Attempt 1:**

Attempt 1 uses `win32com.client`.  I am following this example: [How to copy chart from excel and paste it as chart into powerpoint (not image) using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60445740/how-to-copy-chart-from-excel-and-paste-it-as-chart-into-powerpoint-not-image-u)

but I cannot get the syntax right to insert the chart into the placeholder.  When I follow the syntax in the solution, nothing happens and I get a message

> <bound method Paste of <COMObject >>

Current code:

```python
xlApp = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(outputPath+'Chart Pack.xlsb')
        
pptApp = win32.Dispatch('PowerPoint.Application')
ppt = pptApp.Presentations.Open(template)
        
# attempt 1
wb.sheets('Charts').ChartObjects('Figure1').Copy
ppt.slides[2].Shapes.Paste
    
# attempt 2
wb.sheets('Charts').ChartObjects('Figure1').Copy
ppt.slides[2].placeholders[1].Paste
```

**Attempt 2:**

Attempt 2 uses `python-pptx`.  I looked at the documentation here:
https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/placeholders-using.html

but the example involves creating an excel chart from scratch in PowerPoint (I am not sure why you would ever do that), and I can't figure out the syntax to insert an existing chart from excel.

Current code:

```python
from pptx import Presentation

xlApp = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(outputPath+'Chart Pack.xlsb')
    
prs = Presentation(template)
slide = prs.slides[3]
    
for shape in slide.placeholders:
    print('%d %s' % (shape.placeholder_format.idx, shape.name))

placeholder = prs.slides[3].placeholders[1]
placeholder.name
placeholder.placeholder_format.type
placeholder.insert_chart(wb.sheets('Charts').ChartObjects('Figure1').Copy)
```

**Requirements:**

1. I would like to paste the excel chart as an excel object (rather than as a picture) as my colleague likes to be able to click on data series to get the underlying values etc.
2. I would like to paste the chart inside a placeholder (rather than on top of it).
3. I don't want to generate a new chart in PowerPoint as most examples do.  A colleague has prepared an excel dashboard and formatted a number of charts as desired, and doing it all from scratch would be laborious.
4. I don't want to do this in VBA.  I would like to do it in python as it is part of a broader program.
5. I don't want to use something like `plotnine`, `seaborn`, `matplotlib` etc.  As per 1, my colleague likes excel objects that he can click on to show underlying values.  This can't be done in these programs.

Python should be able to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close! `Copy` and `Paste` are methods, so to call them you need to add brackets after them, e.g. `Copy()`.

To get slide 2, you need to use the `Item` method of the `Slides` class: `ppt.Slides.Item(2)`

```py
import win32com.client as win32

xlApp = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(outputPath+'Chart Pack.xlsb')

pptApp = win32.Dispatch('PowerPoint.Application')
ppt = pptApp.Presentations.Open(template)

slide_num = 3
LEFT_PLACEHOLDER = 3
RIGHT_PLACEHOLDER = 2

# Figure1
window.View.GotoSlide(slide_num)
wb.sheets('Charts').ChartObjects('Figure1').Copy()
ppt.Slides.Item(slide_num).Shapes.Paste().Select()
window.Selection.Cut()
ppt.Slides.Item(slide_num).Shapes(LEFT_PLACEHOLDER).Select()
window.View.Paste()

# Figure2
window.View.GotoSlide(slide_num)
wb.sheets('Charts').ChartObjects('Figure2').Copy()
ppt.Slides.Item(slide_num).Shapes.Paste().Select()
window.Selection.Cut()
ppt.Slides.Item(slide_num).Shapes(RIGHT_PLACEHOLDER).Select()
window.View.Paste()
```

EDIT: I was able to paste the chart directly into the placeholder after fiddling around a bit trying to implement the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061100/3589122). It a bit hacky, but it works.

Comment: Thanks very Gordon, appreciate it.  Is it possible to paste the chart inside the placeholder rather than on top of it?  This has a number of advantages.

Comment: Yeah, probably. What is the placeholder? I suspect you'll need to find the placeholder object, get its position and make it the new chart's position, then delete the placeholder object.

Comment: So, if I run the code based on the python-pptx package, the placeholder in position 1 is called 'Content Placeholder 3'.  I am trying to chain placeholder to the above to see if I can get it to work, but will keep googling.

Comment: Okay, so I didn't realise that _placeholder_ was an actual thing. Ignore my last comment. I've updated by answer, based off this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061100/3589122